# Controlling Start-Up and Shutdown of Camel Routes

Tags: grails, activemq-classic, routes, apache-camel

I am trying to make kind of a polling service towards a activemq queue using camel routes.

I am using routing and routing-jsm plugins for grails.

I have my route configuration set like this.

```
class QueueRoute {
def configure = {
    from("activemq:daemon").routeId("daemonRoute")
    .noAutoStartup()
    .shutdownRunningTask(ShutdownRunningTask.CompleteCurrentTaskOnly)
    .to('bean:daemonCamelService?method=receive')
    .end()
}
```

}

and I am basically trying to do .suspendRoute("daemonRoute") and .resumeRoute("daemonRoute") with some time inbetween. Though after issuing suspendRoute the route is not stopped.

Anyone have tried this?, I have read something about needing to kill the exchange in progress or something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are just trying to periodically process all messages in a queue, then another option (instead of starting and stopping the route) is to use a timer and a [polling consumer](http://camel.apache.org/polling-consumer.html) bean to do retrieve all the messages in the queue...

```
from("timer://processQueueTimer?fixedRate=true&period=30000")
    .to("bean:myBean?method=poll");

public class MyBean {

  public void poll() {
    // loop to empty queue
    while (true) {
        // receive the message from the queue, wait at most 3 sec
        Object msg = consumer.receiveBody("activemq:queue:daemon", 3000);
        if (msg == null) {
            // no more messages in queue
            break;
        }

        // send it to the next endpoint
        producer.sendBody("bean:daemonCamelService?method=receive", msg);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That only poll 1 message from the queue, evert 30th second, and you did not provide a tineout option to pollEnrich which is best practice, which mean you end up having it blocked (thread) if no messages is on the queue. Not a good solution with messaging.

Comment: good point Claus, I thought this would poll until no messages were returned and return a list, but I see what you mean...only one message is received each pass.  Do you think that would be a valid enhancement?

Comment: updated answer to use a bean polling consumer instead of pollEnrich()...per Claus's comments

Comment: Yeah if you want to drain a queue, then you can do it in the while loop from a bean, as the updated example.

Comment: this enhancement would make this a lot easier: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-3211

Answer (score 1):

See this FAQ how to stop/suspend a route from a route
http://camel.apache.org/how-can-i-stop-a-route-from-a-route.html

An alternative is to use a route policy
http://camel.apache.org/routepolicy

For example as we do with the throttling route policy that is provided out of the box, take a look at how its implemented, you can do similar for your route as well.